# fineUploader error handling

Tags: javascript, jquery, fine-uploader

I need to implement a server error during uploading. Here is my code:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#@clientId").fineUploader({
        request: {
            endpoint: '@(Url.Content("~/Admin/Download/AsyncUpload"))'
        },
        template: "@(clientId)-qq-template",
        multiple: false
    }).on("complete", function (event, id, name, responseJSON, xhr) {
        $("#@(clientId + "downloadurl")").html("<a href='" + responseJSON.downloadUrl + "'>@T("Admin.Download.DownloadUploadedFile")</a>");
        $("#@(clientId + "value") input").val(responseJSON.downloadId);
        $("#@(clientId + "remove")").show();
    });
});
```

The manual on [handling errors](http://docs.fineuploader.com/features/handling-errors.html) I have found doesn't help.

Any clue?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @DanBeghin I have server side exception of the file size and I need to display it somehow.  So somehow I have to return the server error message and show it to user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Fine Uploader server can return a number of [response values](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/endpoint_handlers/traditional.html#response). To return a server error message, you can simply return a response `success` value of `false` (which will trigger an error callback) and populate an `error` value with whatever messaging you desire:

```
{
    "success": false,
    "error": "bad filesize"
}
```

To then do something meaningful with this response, simply leverage the `onError` callback:

```
.on("error", function(event, id, name, reason) {
    alert(qq.format("Error on file {} (id = {}). Reason: {}", name, id, reason));
})
```